# Is it correct to perform operations on matrices inside of matrices rather than the whole matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It seems to be a generally useful technique when proving theorems about matrices to consider smaller matrices inside of other matrices. For example, I might write

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} I_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times (m - n)}\end{pmatrix}$$

Then write

$$M M^T = I_{n \times n}$$

This is a true, but in general may I simple perform operations on matrices like this?

As another example, can I write (where A, B, and I are all matrices):

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix}$$

Then say:

$$ |M| = \begin{vmatrix} |A| & |B| \\ |0| & |I| \end{vmatrix} = |A| |I| - |0| |B| = |A|$$

Comment: Please replace each `x` with `\times`.

Comment: In short, yes. Try writing out some block products element by element using the basic definition of matrix multiplication.